# Finding the square root of an element in a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Considering the polynomial ring $\frac{\mathbb{k}[x,y]}{(x^{N-1},y^{N-1})}$ for $N\in \mathbb{N}$ odd, I am interested in finding the square root of the element $\theta^2=(N-1)x^{N-2}y^{N-2}$.

I managed to do it in the case of $N=3$ where one has $\theta^2=2xy=2xy+x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2$ thus $\theta=(x+y)$. Generally I would have guessed that $\theta=(x+y)^{N-2}$ for general $N$, but this is false. I am now trying a more methodical approach where I have tried to look at the case $N=5$ to perhaps see a pattern and try some induction argument for general $N$, but all I found was $\theta^2=(x+y)^6-16x^3y^3$ not giving me any clues.
Alternatively one could make an Ansatz of the form $\theta^{2}=(\sum_{i,j}^{N-1}a_{i,j}x^iy^j)(\sum_{i,j}^{N-1}a_{k,l}x^ky^l)=(N-1)x^{N-2}y^{N-2}$ and try to solve for the coefficients. That seems very tedious and inefficient however for general $N$.

If anyone could help me out or even direct me to a more efficient way to calculate the square root in this polynomial ring that would even generalize to other cases it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for $N=3$ can be generalised, but not using your approach. One way to do this is:
$$
\begin{align}
(N-1)x^{N-2}y^{N-2} &= \frac{N-1}{2}\left[(x^{N-2}+y^{N-2})^2-x^{2(N-2)}-y^{2(N-2)}\right] \\
&=\left[\sqrt{\frac{N-1}{2}}(x^{N-2}+y^{N-2})\right]^2
\end{align}
$$
using $2(N-2)\geq N-1$ if $N\geq 3$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is $(N-1)/2$ a square?

Comment: $\theta = x^{N-2}+\frac{N-1}{2}y^{N-2}$?

Comment: Thanks for fixing it @ReneSchoof. lhf I made some simplifying assumptions. For example I also assumed $\mathbb k$ not to be of characteristic $2$.

Comment: What happens if $\mathbb k = \mathbb Q$?

Comment: ReneSchoof’s solution always works in this case.